# How to draw a haar wavelet plot using pywt?

Tags: python, wavelet, haar-wavelet, pywt

I'm only in the beginning of learning wavelet transformation, so I have such naive question.

I have quite simple scaling function with only two non-zero coefficients:

[image]

```
h(0) = h(1) = 1/ sqrt(2)
```

I have calculated the average and difference part on my own, and now I want to draw a plot to describe my DWT.

How to show this plot using `pywt` library on interval [0,1]

My vector is `a = [8,2,1,6,3,−9,7,4]`

My graph, should look like something similar to this one: https://yadi.sk/i/3MIfn3tF3NRFsB

Comment: use :  https://matplotlib.org/

Comment: @Dadep Thanks, but my question was mostly about, which variables should I send to plot() function.

Answer (score -1):

It is to really clear what you are doing, but to get something that look like the image you gave the link, you can do :

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a = [8,2,1,6,3,-9,7,4]
>>> x = [float(i)/len(a) for i in range(len(a))]
>>> plt.step(x,a)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f49fa6868d0>]
>>> plt.show()
```

to obtain :
[image]